# They didn't finish playing (by 10.30). vs They hadn't finished playing (by 10.30)

Tags: past-tense

I have a sentence:
"At 10.30 they were playing tennis."
After that, could the next sentence be written in past simple?

> They didn't finish playing.
>
> They hadn't finished playing.

In my grammar book is used past perfect, not past simple. And I don't understand why past perfect was chosen. Could you explain it, please? What's the difference in meaning here? I know that past perfect is used to describe actions in the past before past.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the next sentence could be written in the simple past tense. Or it could be written in the past perfect.  The difference would only become apparent when placed into a longer context.

> They were playing tennis at 10:30.  They hadn't finished playing by 11:00 (and so they were still playing at that time).

> They were playing tennis at 10:30. They didn't finish until 11:00 (and so they finished at that time).

Now I think your grammar book is doing something different.  It is giving a rephrasing.

> They were playing tennis at 10:30

... means the same as ...

> They had not finished playing by 10:30

These aren't two sentences, one after the other, forming a narrative, it is a sentence and a repetition the meaning of that sentence with different phrasing.

Comment: Thank you for your good explanation with time. But I'm trying to understand my grammar book logic. As I understand, there is speaking about 10.30 am. So, is it possible to say: 1) They didn't finish playing by 10.30. 2) They hadn't finished playing by 10.30. **And what's the difference in meaning?**

Comment: I guess Past perfect can't be used in the same time with past continuous or past simple. I mean that actions with Past perfect must be used at least slightly before actions with past continuous or past simple. Is it right? So, why did the author use there past perfect? )

Comment: You need to give more context.  There's nothing wrong with having one sentence in using a past continuous verb, and the next having past perfect.

Comment: But I suspect that your book is doing something different.  It is giving an rephrasing.  I'll add that angle to the ansser

Comment: I got your idea. Can past simple be used there instead of past perfect? I read in another grammar book that we can do that if the consequence of actions is clear. So, the choice of past simple or past perfect there doesn't change the meaning of the sentence. Right?

Comment: "They didn't finish playing by 10:30" would pretty much mean the same, the past perfect is only for the absence of doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Both sentences are possible after "*At 10.30 they were playing tennis*", but they have different meanings.

> At 10.30 they were playing tennis. They didn't finish playing.

This means their game was interrupted for some reason, so they stopped playing, and they didn't complete their game.

> At 10.30 they were playing tennis. They hadn't finished playing.

This means they were still playing at 10:30, and the game was not yet finished. The past perfect here is the past form of *present perfect*. It doesn't mean the past of the past, but the past form of "*They haven't finished playing*".

Comment: I guess you have a logical mistake here in your explanation about 'They didn't finish playing.': "This means their game was interrupted for some reason, so they stopped playing, and they didn't complete their game."

Comment: There's two meanings of "finish". One is to complete something, the other is to stop something. In the first sentence, the meaning is "complete". In the second sentence, the meaning could be stop or complete.